# Stop propagation of drag event

Tags: javascript, events, leaflet

How can I stop the propagation of the drag event ?

Currently my current code looks like that :

```
map.on('drag', function(e) {
    e.originalEvent.preventDefault();
    e.originalEvent.stopPropagation();
    console.log('event');
    return false;
});
```

The event is correctly triggered because I can see the log in my console but the map keeps being dragged despite the call to `preventDefault` and `stopPropagation`, any idea ?

Comment: have you tried just e.preventDefault() & e.stopPropagation() ?

Comment: Yes, it throws the error : TypeError: e.preventDefault is not a function.

Comment: Ok what is the overall issue? The drag event is bubbling up to another element being dragged? It's not clear what you're trying to accomplish

Comment: My overrall goal is to disable the dragging on mobile, but I also want to display a message to the user to tell him to use two fingers when he tries to drag the map. I tried to set the `dragging` option to `false` when I create my map, but it prevents the drag event to be be triggered.

Comment: maybe this can help? Shows how to set map options https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/281202/disable-map-panning-using-the-arrow-keys-in-the-keyboard - Edit just seen you're edit (nevermind!)

Comment: As I said, if the `dragging` option is set to `false`, the `drag` event is not triggered anymore which makes it impossible to display an information message when the user try to drag the map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edited to reflect suggestion in comments**

Stopping propagation on the drag event didn't work i.e.

```
map.on('drag', function(e) {
     $(this).dragging.disable();
     return false;
});
```

OP was trying to prevent dragging on the map unless it was a 2 finger drag. In order to accomplish this it was suggested to overlay the map with a transparent div, and then hide the div when a two fingered gesture event is fired on it. Something like...

HTML

```
<div class='map-container'>
    <div class='overlay' style='width:100%; hwight:100%; background-color:transparent;'>
    </div>
    <div class='map'>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS/Jquery

```
$('.overlay').on('touchstart', function (e) {
if (e.touches.length > 1)
    $(this).hide();
});

$('.overlay').on('touchend', function (e){
    $(this).show();
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I already tried that, the issue is that it won't propagate the drag event to the page. When the user drag the map, it should scrolls on the page instead.

Comment: ah I see what you mean, just off the top of my head - you could add an overlay to the map that would then negate the need for dragging and allow you to maintain page scroll, then hide when 2 fingers are detected on it?

Comment: That's a good idea, if I don't have another anwser before monday, I'll accept your. :)

Comment: Don't want to be the bad guy here, but please don't accept a not-working answer just for the good intentions, someone may end up here with the same issue and waste time trying something not useful.

If you accept it because of the comments, edit it to containt the solution.

Comment: I intended to amend the answer if the solution in the comments worked mate. No point changing it yet though

Comment: The solution in the comment worked so maybe you should update your answer before I accept it.